# How to access parameters in a Parameterized Build?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How do you access `parameters` set in the "This build is parameterized" section of a "Workflow" Jenkins job?

**TEST CASE**

1. Create a WORKFLOW job.
2. Enable "This build is parameterized".
3. Add a STRING PARAMETER `foo` with default value `bar text`.
4. Add the code below to `Workflow Script`:

   ```
   node()
   {
        print "DEBUG: parameter foo = ${env.foo}"
   }
   ```
5. Run job.

**RESULT**

`DEBUG: parameter foo = null`

Comment: Another misconception (autojack in #jenkins: [transcript](http://echelog.com/logs/browse/jenkins/1427925600)) is that you should use `$foo`, as in `if ($PARAM == 'true') {…}`. That is just a variable identifier in Groovy. `$` is only a metacharacter within some kinds of strings.

Comment: To modify Jenkins params, try EnvInject plugin. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7067223/658497

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I tried a few of the solutions from this thread. It seemed to work, but my values were always true and I also encountered the following issue:
[JENKINS-40235](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40235)

I managed to use parameters in groovy `jenkinsfile` using the following syntax: `params.myVariable`

Here's a working example:

### Solution

```
print 'DEBUG: parameter isFoo = ' + params.isFoo
print "DEBUG: parameter isFoo = ${params.isFoo}"
```

### A more detailed (and working) example:

```
node() {
   // adds job parameters within jenkinsfile
   properties([
     parameters([
       booleanParam(
         defaultValue: false,
         description: 'isFoo should be false',
         name: 'isFoo'
       ),
       booleanParam(
         defaultValue: true,
         description: 'isBar should be true',
         name: 'isBar'
       ),
     ])
   ])

   // test the false value
   print 'DEBUG: parameter isFoo = ' + params.isFoo
   print "DEBUG: parameter isFoo = ${params.isFoo}"
   sh "echo sh isFoo is ${params.isFoo}"
   if (params.isFoo) { print "THIS SHOULD NOT DISPLAY" }

   // test the true value
   print 'DEBUG: parameter isBar = ' + params.isBar
   print "DEBUG: parameter isBar = ${params.isBar}"
   sh "echo sh isBar is ${params.isBar}"
   if (params.isBar) { print "this should display" }
}
```

### Output

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] properties
WARNING: The properties step will remove all JobPropertys currently configured in this job, either from the UI or from an earlier properties step.
This includes configuration for discarding old builds, parameters, concurrent builds and build triggers.
WARNING: Removing existing job property 'This project is parameterized'
WARNING: Removing existing job property 'Build triggers'
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG: parameter isFoo = false
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG: parameter isFoo = false
[Pipeline] sh
[wegotrade-test-job] Running shell script
+ echo sh isFoo is false
sh isFoo is false
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG: parameter isBar = true
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG: parameter isBar = true
[Pipeline] sh
[wegotrade-test-job] Running shell script
+ echo sh isBar is true
sh isBar is true
[Pipeline] echo
this should display
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

*I sent a [Pull Request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/pull/425) to update the misleading [pipeline tutorial#build-parameters](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#build-parameters) quote that says "they are accessible as Groovy variables of the same name."*. ;)

*Edit:* As Jesse Glick pointed out:
[Release notes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Groovy+Plugin#PipelineGroovyPlugin-2.18%28Sep23%2C2016%29) go into more details

> You should also update the Pipeline Job Plugin to 2.7 or later, so that build parameters are defined as environment variables and thus accessible as if they were global Groovy variables.

Comment: Parameters continue to be available without `params` as before (as flat strings, no default value support). They are technically now environment variables, though you can still refer to their values using a bare expression since the `env.` prefix is now also optional for accesses. [Release notes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Groovy+Plugin#PipelineGroovyPlugin-2.18%28Sep23%2C2016%29) go into more detail.

Comment: This really helped me to solve my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115868/jenkins-groovy-url-get-parameter/42153457#42153457
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any clue how i could proceed with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277315/jenkins-groovy-extend-properties-array ?

Comment: @Basti: Jon S's answer is right in your Q/A, you must call `properties` only once or rewrite all params each time.

Comment: `The properties section has been renamed as of version 0.8. Use options instead.` This no longer works

Comment: Indeed. I'm not using Jenkins anymore, but feel free to edit this post with the right syntax. I suppose we can just rename `properties` with `options` and it will keep working. Reference for the rename: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/12/declarative-pipeline-beta-2/

Comment: You should use `params.myparam`, not `myparam`.  The former retains type information, so if your parameter is a boolean, the value will be a boolean.  The latter converts the value to a string

Comment: Where the heck is the documentation for `params.`??

Comment: @Snowcrash https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters here

Answer (score 103):

I think the variable is available directly, rather than through env, when using Workflow plugin.
Try:

```
node()
{
    print "DEBUG: parameter foo = ${foo}"
}
```

Comment: Correct, as explained [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#build-parameters).

Comment: but to make it available for a shell task, I seem to have to assign to 'env' - that feels strange...
e.g.: 
env.PARAM = PARAM

Comment: no, I was wrong - I was using sh '''echo X''' instead of sh """echo X"""

Comment: Make sure to use double quotes instead of single quote. The latter will skip interpolation.

Comment: Make sure you don't use "env" as one of your parameters as it is a reserved keyword and it won't work

Comment: In most cases, using single quote is fine, but sometimes it fails unless you use double quotes. What is the rule to determine that using single qoute fails or not ?

Answer (score 17):

When you add a build parameter, foo,
it gets converted to something which acts like a "bare variable",
so in your script you would do:

```
node {
   echo foo
}
```

If you look at the implementation of the workflow script, you will see that when a script is executed, a class called WorkflowScript is
dynamically generated.  All statements in the script are executed in the context of this class.  All build parameters passed down to this script are converted to properties which are accessible from this class.

For example, you can do:

```
node {
    getProperty("foo")
}
```

If you are curious, here is a workflow script I wrote which attempts to print out the build parameters, environment variables, and methods on the WorkflowScript class.

```
node {
   echo "I am a "+getClass().getName()

   echo "PARAMETERS"
   echo "=========="
   echo getBinding().getVariables().getClass().getName()
   def myvariables = getBinding().getVariables()
   for (v in myvariables) {
       echo "${v} " + myvariables.get(v)
   }
   echo STRING_PARAM1.getClass().getName()

   echo "METHODS"
   echo "======="
   def methods = getMetaClass().getMethods()

   for (method in methods) {
       echo method.getName()    
   } 

   echo "PROPERTIES"
   echo "=========="
   properties.each{ k, v -> 
       println "${k} ${v}" 
   }
   echo properties
   echo properties["class"].getName()

   echo "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES"
   echo "======================"
   echo "env is " + env.getClass().getName()
   def envvars = env.getEnvironment()
   envvars.each{ k, v ->
        println "${k} ${v}"
   }
}
```

Here is another code example I tried, where I wanted to test to see
if a build parameter was set or not.

```
node {
   groovy.lang.Binding myBinding = getBinding()
   boolean mybool = myBinding.hasVariable("STRING_PARAM1")
   echo mybool.toString()
   if (mybool) {
       echo STRING_PARAM1
       echo getProperty("STRING_PARAM1")
   } else {
       echo "STRING_PARAM1 is not defined"
   }

   mybool = myBinding.hasVariable("DID_NOT_DEFINE_THIS")
   if (mybool) {
       echo DID_NOT_DEFINE_THIS
       echo getProperty("DID_NOT_DEFINE_THIS")
   } else {
       echo "DID_NOT_DEFINE_THIS is not defined"
   }
}
```

Comment: For me this produces: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.lang.Class getName

Answer (score 10):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes

e.g. `echo "$foo"` as opposed to `echo '$foo'`

If you configured your pipeline to accept parameters using the Build with Parameters option, those parameters are accessible as Groovy variables of the same name. See [Here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/#build-parameters).

You can drop the semicolon (`;`), drop the parentheses (`( and )`), and use single quotes (`'`) instead of double (`"`) **if you do not need to perform variable substitutions**. See [Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#understanding-pipeline-scripts). This clued me into my problem, though I've found that only the double (`"`) is required to make it work.

Comment: Links in your answer no longer point to the correct content. I know the answer is a bit dated. But I just stumbled across it looking for answers.

Answer (score 9):

To parameter variable add prefix "params."
For example:

```
params.myParam
```

Don't forget: if you use some method of myParam, may be you should approve it in "Script approval".

Answer (score 7):

You can also try using **parameters** directive for making your build parameterized and accessing parameters:

Doc:
[Pipeline syntax: Parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters)

Example:

```
pipeline{

agent { node { label 'test' } }
options { skipDefaultCheckout() }

parameters {
    string(name: 'suiteFile', defaultValue: '', description: 'Suite File')
}
stages{

    stage('Initialize'){

        steps{

          echo "${params.suiteFile}"

        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope the following piece of code works for you:

```
def item = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem('MyJob')

def value = item.lastBuild.getEnvironment(null).get('foo')
```

Comment: This is much too much work, and will not even work if you are using “sandbox” mode, or there are concurrent builds of the project.

Comment: You can also use `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance`

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet gives you access to all Job params

```
    def myparams = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(ParametersAction)
    for( p in myparams ) {
        pMap[p.name.toString()] = p.value.toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note, the way that build parameters are accessed inside pipeline scripts (pipeline plugin) has changed. This approach:

```
getBinding().hasVariable("MY_PARAM")
```

Is not working anymore. Please try this instead:

```
def myBool = env.getEnvironment().containsKey("MY_BOOL") ? Boolean.parseBoolean("$env.MY_BOOL") : false
```

Comment: I tried this and `env.getEnvironment()` fails with the following error:
`Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.EnvironmentAction getEnvironment`

Comment: @GabLeRoux you can add the permission in Jenkins under Manage Jenkins > In-process Script Approval (which is possibly not super good idea in some cases because you'll have a weaker security)

Comment: Indeed, that would probably work, but I prefer keeping the security risks low :) I managed to get it working and [posted this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41276956/1092815)

Answer (score 1):

As per [Pipeline plugin tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#build-parameters):

> If you have configured your pipeline to accept parameters when it is built — Build with Parameters — they are accessible as Groovy **variables of the same name**.

So try to access the variable directly, e.g.:

```
node()
{
     print "DEBUG: parameter foo = " + foo
     print "DEBUG: parameter bar = ${bar}"
}
```