# How can I pass parameters to the Jenkins build flow?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

How can I pass parameters to the Jenkins build flow?

I have a build flow which runs 4 jobs in sequence . Lets take example :

```
build("job1", param1:value1, param2:value2)
build("job2", param1:value1, param2:value2)
build("job3", param1:value1, param2:value2)
build("job4", param1:value1, param2:value2)
```

I am passing 2 parameters to each job. Parameters are same. So I want to pass "param1","param2" to the build flow. How can I do that ?

Comment: What Jenkins plugin are you using exactly?

Comment: Please check the below thread. It has the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572080/jenkins-workflow-how-to-access-parameters-in-a-parameterized-build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass parameters to the build flow as build
("job1", param1: $parametertothebuildflow1, param2:$parametertothebuildflow1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

pass your parameters with **double quotes**

```
build("job1", param1:"value1", param2:"value2")
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a parameter to a downstream job, use the  [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

Comment: I have used the same plugin for defining parameters. How can I pass it to the script ? 
AS in if it is a batch script , we can pass parameters as %param1 .. How can I pass parameter to the build flow ?

Comment: I still don't understand, where your problem exactly is. Do you want to know 1) how to define that a job takes parameters, 2) how to manually pass parameters to the first job, 3) how to access the parameters when calling a batch file within a single job? 4) how to propagate the parameters to a downstream job? Please edit your question!

Comment: I got an answer ! I can pass the parameter to the DSL script $Parameter