# How to call a build flow from a build flow passing different parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I have 3 Jobs (let's name it as job1,job2,job3) which all accepts same parameters. I have a build flow calling these jobs
Eg Build Flow::

```
build(job1, param1 : "value1", param2 : "value2" )
build(job2, param1 : "value1", param2 : "value2" )
build(job3, param1 : "value1", param2 : "value2" )
```

As you see in the example all the jobs accept same parameters.

And I want to run the same sequence in the build flow (job1, job2, job3) with different parameter values. 
So Now I am having different build flows to pass different values to the parameter:

eg:

```
Build flow1---
build(job1, param1 : "value1", param2 : "value2" )
build(job2, param1 : "value1", param2 : "value2" )
build(job3, param1 : "value1", param2 : "value2" )

Build flow2---
build(job1, param1 : "value3", param2 : "value4" )
build(job2, param1 : "value3", param2 : "value4" )
build(job3, param1 : "value3", param2 : "value4" )
```

I am thinking to have a build flow as shared and able to pass parameters to it 
like :
Example:::

```
Build flow
build(job1, param1 : $paramvalue1, param2 : $paramvalue2 )
build(job2, param1 : $paramvalue1, param2 : $paramvalue2 )
build(job3, param1 : $paramvalue1, param2 : $paramvalue2 )
```

And I want to call this build flow with different parameter values from another build flow.

Can I do that ??? If yes ,,
1. How to define and pass parameter to the flow ?

Comment: Please check the below thread. It has the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572080/jenkins-workflow-how-to-access-parameters-in-a-parameterized-build

Answer (score 1):

You can use Workflow Plugin to achieve what you want.

1. `job1`, `job2` and `job3` must be parameterized jobs with `param1` and `param2` as parameters (they can be freestyle jobs or whatever you want).
2. Create a parameterized Workflow job with `param1` and `param2` as parameters. The workflow script would be something like this:

   ```
   build job: 'job1', parameters: 
     [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: param1],
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param2', value: param2]]
   build job: 'job2', parameters: 
     [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: param1],
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param2', value: param2]]
   build job: 'job3', parameters: 
     [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: param1],
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param2', value: param2]]
   ```
3. Then just run the top level job, it will ask you for parameters values and downstream jobs will be triggered (and top level parameters passed).