# Executing Jenkins job sequentially for multiple Parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have three jobs A, B and C. A is my master job from where I'm calling B and then from B, I'm calling job name C. Now A has two parameters p,q. I want to run B and C job sequentially for p first and then for q.

I googled and found 'Parameterized Trigger Plugin' can be used to pass the parameter from A to B and then from B to C. But how will I repeat this step for second parameter?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a build flow from a build flow passing different parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864248/how-to-call-a-build-flow-from-a-build-flow-passing-different-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

In my jobs for those cases I use matrix plugin in addition to Parameterized Trigger Plugin. Thus job B to be executed with params p and q in sequence.

Comment: so does it repeat the sequence for second parameter?