# How to write properly an if statement in regards to a BooleanParameter in Jenkins pipeline Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting a Jenkins pipeline Jenkinsfile and I'd like to check if a booleanparameter is set.

Here's the relevant portion of the file:

```
node ("master") {
        stage 'Setup' (
                [[$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'BUILD_SNAPSHOT', value: 'Boolean.valueOf(BUILD_SNAPSHOT)']],
```

As I understand, that is the way to access the booleanparameter but I'm not sure how to state the IF statement itself.

I was thinking about doing something like:

```
if(BooleanParameterValue['BUILD_SNAPSHOT']){...
```

What is the correct way to write this statement please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is actually way simpler than that ! 
According to the [pipeline documention](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#build-parameters), if you define a boolean parameter `isFoo` you can access it in your Groovy with just its name, so your script would actually look like :

```
node {
   stage 'Setup'
   echo "${isFoo}"   // Usage inside a string
   if(isFoo) {       // Very simple "if" usage
       echo "Param isFoo is true"
       ...
   }
}
```

And by the way, you probably should'nt call your parameter `BUILD_SNAPSHOT` but maybe `buildSnapshot` or `isBuildSnapshot` because it is a parameter and not a constant.

Comment: I'm having kind of the same problem. Your solution works when `isFoo` is true, but not when it's set to false. On my side, `echo "${isFoo}"` prints "false", but I still see "Param isFoo is true". I used the generator to generate boolean parameters properties.

Comment: ok turned out this is not well documented. I managed to get this working, I posted an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41276956/1092815

Answer (score 33):

A boolean parameter is accessible to your pipeline script in 3 ways:

1. As a bare parameter, e.g: `isFoo`
2. From the `env` map, e.g: `env.isFoo`
3. From the `params` map, e.g: `params.isFoo`

If you access `isFoo` using 1) or 2) it will have a String value (of either "true" or "false").

If you access `isFoo` using 3) it will have a Boolean value.

So the least confusing way (IMO) to test the `isFoo` parameter in your script is like this:

```
if (params.isFoo) {
   ....
}
```

Alternatively you can test it like this:

```
if (isFoo.toBoolean()) {
   ....
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

or

```
if (env.isFoo.toBoolean()) {
   ....
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

the `toBoolean()` is required to convert the `"true"` String to a boolean `true` and the `"false"` String to a boolean `false`.

Answer (score 6):

simply doing `if(isFoo){...}` that will not guarantee it working :) To be safe, use `if(isFoo.toString()=='true'){ ... }`

Comment: So why not `if (isFoo.toBoolean())` then?

Comment: @avtomaton That's okay if it's a `booleanParam` type (and it probably should be). But if it's a choice parameter, it would be `true` if the String value has any content whatsoever. I would suggest in that case using `isFoo.toString().toLowerCase()=='true'` to be more appropriate.