# Jenkins Groovy URL get parameter

Tags: url, jenkins, groovy, parameters

In my Jenkins multi pipeline project i am having a input step like this:

```
input message: 'Merge', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: true, description: '', name: "Merge ${branchConfig.merge} to ${env.BRANCH_NAME}?"]]
```

I am starting this job by calling this url:

http://user:api-token@awesome.jenkins.de/job/myTest/job/dev/build

Now I want to add a GET parameter like this:

http://user:api-token@awesome.jenkins.de/job/myTest/job/dev/build?skipInput=true

My question now is, how can I get this parameter in groovy?

UPDATE: Following the first comment, I did the following:

```
// Add parameter to skip MergeInput.
properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', name: 'skipMergeInput', defaultValue: false]]]])
```

And adjusted the input like that:

```
input message: 'Merge', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: params.skipMergeInput, description: '', name: "Merge ${branchConfig.merge} to ${env.BRANCH_NAME}?"]]
```

When I am now starting my job, it shows me a popup that ask for the value that should be set. But no matter what i decide, the input is always false. I am trying to figure out what is going wrong and will update my post then.

UPDATE 2:
So I kept on debugging. I added the following to my groovy script:

```
// Add parameter to skip MergeInput.
def doMerge = properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', name: 'doMerge', defaultValue: true]]]])
println doMerge;
```

The output returns me NULL, and when I am doing something like

```
println params.doMerge
```

It tells me that params is not defined. Any idea what is going wrong?

UPDATE 3:

Call URL: /job/dg_test/job/master/buildWithParameters?test=true

Groovy Script:

```
properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', name: 'test', defaultValue: false]]]])
println params.test
```

Result:

```
No such property: params for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved it, this post really helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41276956/1565249

And this is my implementation:

```
// Add fancy build parameter.
properties([
  parameters([
    booleanParam(
      defaultValue: false,
      description: 'Some description',
      name: 'developmentMerge'
    ),
  ])
])

if (developmentMerge == "true" || developmentMerge == true) {
  // Your code here
}
else {
  // Your code here
}
```

When I now start my job manually from the GUI, it asks me which value should be set for "developmentMerge".

And I also can start my job by calling this URL: 
"/job/dg_test/job/master/buildWithParameters?developmentMerge=true"

Where "dg_test" is the name of my Jenkins project and "master" is the job i wanted to start.

The if statement must be done like this:

```
if (developmentMerge == "true" || developmentMerge == true)
```

because when you start the job from GUI, it will send a boolean "true", but when you start the job by the URL call, you receive a string.

Comment: Oh, we get strings from url I didn't use build urls yet, that's good to know! Nice catch :)

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable in 3 simple steps:

1. Set a boolean parameter for your pipeline build:
   [image]
2. Use the "params." prefix to access your parameter in your input message step:

   ```
   input message: 'Merge', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: params.skipInput, description: '', name: "Merge ${branchConfig.merge} to ${env.BRANCH_NAME}?"]]
   ```
3. Use the "buildWithParameters" api command rather than "build":
   http://user:api-token@awesome.jenkins.de/job/myTest/job/dev/buildWithParameters?skipInput=true

Comment: Since I am using a groovy file, I can not simply add build parameters to my job configuration. This is what I have done now: (update in my post)

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the api using the "/buildWithParameters" and not just "/build". It looks like the parameter is not being transferred at all.

Comment: Very sure, see my Update 3