# Jenkins Groovy extend properties array

Tags: arrays, jenkins, groovy, parameters, properties

Inside my jenkinsfile I want to set multiple properties based on some dependencies.

So in the top of my jenkinsfile I am setting my first parameter:

```
properties([
  parameters([
    booleanParam(
      defaultValue: false,
      description: '...',
      name: 'parameters1'
    ),
  ])
])
```

Some lines below I want to set another parameter if a condition is met

```
if(awesomeCondition) {
  properties([
    parameters([
      booleanParam(
        defaultValue: false,
        description: '...',
        name: 'parameters2'
      ),
    ])
  ])
}
```

The problem I am now running into is that the second parameter is overriding the first parameter. How to handle this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `properties` step overrides the existing job properties so, as you noted, the second call overrides the previous one. This is expected behaviour.

What you need to do is to keep a list of new parameters and then use a single call to `properties` step:

```
def newParameters = []
newParameters.add([
  $class: 'hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition',
  name: "p1",
  default: false,
  description:"Some help text"
])
...
if(awesomeCondition) {
  newParameters.add([
    $class: 'hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition',
    name: "p2",
    default: false,
    description:"Some help text"
  ])
}
...
properties([parameters(newParameters)])
```

The `$class: 'hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition'` is needed since we are creating the objects outside of the `properties` step. For other types of parameters see sub-classes to [this class](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/ParameterDefinition.html).

Comment: Nice one, I will give this a try tomorrow and update this thread then.

Comment: Tested and approved. One note for everyone else reading this, you should prepare your parameters in the top of your jenkinsfile. Adding them later resulted in problems in my case.