# Jenkins pipeline cannot access parameters once installed in GUI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins ver. 2.121.1

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        string(
            name: 'repo',
            defaultValue:"foo",
            description: "repo to build from")
    }

    agent any

    stages {
            stage('Checkout'){
                steps {
                    echo params.repo
```

Expected:
echo prints "foo" or what ever value was set at "build with parameters" every time.

Actual:
The first time the pipeline is run the default value is printed.
Once the parameters are "installed" and visible in the GUI, every run after that the echo line prints empty string

Does anyone know what is causing this interference in the parameters being accessible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572080/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-parameterized-build

Comment: Nope, you can refer to the parameters through `params`, that's correct to the best of my knowledge. This will be defined (but `null`) during the initial run compare to referring directly to the variable.

Comment: So I just noticed if I undefine the parameterization in the web interface, the first time it runs, this works and print's the default value, however once the parameter is "installed" in jenkins, then it fails on all successive runs