# How to read parameters sent by an upstream job in a downstream job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have an upstream pipeline job that triggers a downstream pipeline job, the upstream job sends a few parameters to the downstream job. How should I read these parameters in the downstream job? Both jobs are non-parameterized.

The upstream job sends parameters like so.

```
build job: 'downstream-job', 
        parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Environment', value: "dev"]]
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29299889/7713802) answer says uses the variable directly but this doesn't seem to work. When I try using the variable `Environment` in the downstream job, I get an error saying.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Environment for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#build-parameters), it has to be `params.Environment`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with downstream job, because it's non-parameterized. And if downstream job is non-parameterized, it just ignores your parameters. 
From [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170) page:

> Parameterized Trigger Plugin Parameters (e.g. when using properties
>   files as source) are only passed if they are defined on the downstream
>   job. This is the behavior intended by the SECURITY-170, see Jenkins
>   Security Advisory 2016-05-11

Also from description of [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin):

> *** YOU MUST DEFINE THE PARAMETER IN DOWNSTREAM JOBS VIA  "This project is parameterized". For example, if job1 passes ABC=123 to job2 then in job2 mark the job as "This project is parameterized" and "Add Parameter" named "ABC". ***

Comment: I was able to accept parameters in the downstream job using `params.variableName`