# Jenkins - Setting parameters for a parametirized build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Jenkins jobs - job A (located on server A) triggers job B (located on server B). These servers are internal to my company - we have it set up now that server A can trigger the job on server B. The job on server B requires parameters for it to build.

There a multiple `build job` stages that get triggered in job B when a parameter is set to a particular value (when job type is set to install). Since all these stages used the same parameters, I am trying to do it in such a way that I only need to set the parameters once instead of just copying and pasting the code from the pipeline for each `build job`.

I have tried looking online for a way to do this but there doesn't seem to much. All I have found is the following:

`params.myParam = "some value"`

and the following: [How to access parameters in a Parameterized Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572080/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-parameterized-build)

From the above linked question, would I have to do the following in my JenkinsfilePreCommit (a groovy file):

```
properties([
     parameters([
       booleanParam(
         defaultValue: false,
         description: 'isFoo should be false',
         name: 'isFoo'
       ),
```

where booleanParam can be replaced with whatever type of param it is, defaultValue is the value I want to set it to, description being optional, and name is the name of the parameter in the Jenkins build? i.e job_type

Comment: Do I understand correctly that job B triggers more jobs and you want to pass the parameters down like this: job A -> job B -> job B children builds?

Comment: @Moro Not quite, job A would trigger job B - job B performs an install of helm charts on a environment  (not on jenkins)

So it would be job A builds -> trigger job B -> job B performs a task on a environment

Comment: Can you share the Jenkinsfile of Job A and Job B, especially Job B

Comment: Parameters are automatically considered to be env variables, so you can just say `env.isFoo` and refer to the variable anywhere. Is there something preventing you from doing that?