# String parameter passing in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am developing a pipeline where in when triggered it should display the parameters and below is the code

```
node {

stage('preparation')  {
               timeout(time:15, unit:'MINUTES') {
    id: 'userInput', message: 'preparation',
                    parameters: [
                                [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'cicd', description: 'dev env', name: 'DEV_PROJECT'],
                               [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'test', description: 'stage env', name: 'STAGE_PROJECT'],
                               [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'jboss', description: 'Image Name', name: 'IMAGE_NAME'],
                             ] )

                       input message: "Is the PARAMETERS(can be visible on leftside) are correctly set for deployment?", ok: "Promote" }
echo "${DEV_PROJECT}"
echo "${STAGE_PROJECT}"
echo "${IMAGE_NAME}"
}
```

When i do echo its not populating the values of user input.
Iam getting below error. My requirement is the user can input the DEV_PROJECT,STAGE_PROJECT and IMAGE_NAME and the values entered by him should be used in the pipeline scripts down the line in build and deploy stages.Iam getting below error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: DEV_PROJECT for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:284)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:288)
```

could anyone let me know how to proceed?

Comment: Try `params.DEV_PROJECT` instead.

Comment: its displaying [Pipeline] echo
params.DEV_PROJECT
[Pipeline] echo
params.STAGE_PROJECT
[Pipeline] echo
params.IMAGE_NAME

Comment: They are still variables. You cannot output the literal string and expect it to interpolate. Try again and just replace the variable you had with my suggestion of using the `params` map and see if that works.

Comment: Try EnvInject plugin. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7067223/658497

Answer (score -1):

If you have configured your pipeline to accept parameters when it is built — **Build with Parameters** — they are accessible as Groovy variables inside `params`.

**Example**: Using `isFoo` parameter defined as a boolean parameter (checkbox in the GUI):

```java
node {
  sh "isFoo is ${params.isFoo}"
  sh 'isFoo is ' + params.isFoo
  if (params.isFoo) {
    // do something
}
```

Reference: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference